# Powershell: How to call a funtion for the second time to give only one parameter?

Tags: powershell

I have the following function to create a statusbox(to show msg)

```
function Statusbox([string]$StatusboxOn, $StatusboxText, $AddStatusboxto) {
    # Label-Statusbox. Beschriftung.
    $LBStatusbox          = new-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
    #$LBStatusbox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size($StatusboxLocationX, ($StatusboxLocationY-23))
    $LBStatusbox.AutoSize = $True
    $LBStatusbox.text     = "Status"
    $LBStatusbox.Font     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("arial",12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::bold)
    
    # TextBox. Dies ist ein Info-Box. Hier werden Infos angezeigt.
    $textboxStatusbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    
    if($StatusboxOn -eq "HF"){
        $textboxStatusbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(810, 440)
        $textboxStatusbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240, 30)
        $LBStatusbox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(810, 417)
        "this one: " +$StatusboxOn
    }
    else {
        $textboxStatusbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,0)
        $textboxStatusbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,0)
        $LBStatusbox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(0,0)
        "else one: " +$StatusboxOn
    }
    # Readonly Textbox.
    $textboxStatusbox.Enabled = $false
    $textboxStatusbox.Text = $StatusboxText
    $textboxStatusbox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 12)
    $AddStatusboxto.Controls.Add($LBStatusbox)
    $AddStatusboxto.Controls.Add($textboxStatusbox)
}
```

in my skript i call this function at the beginning sothat an empty textbox will be shown.

```
Statusbox -StatusboxOn "HF" -AddStatusboxto $ButtonPanel
```

After that if i have to give a msg. i only call the function like this

```
Statusbox -StatusboxText "Loading...   Please wait." -AddStatusboxto $ButtonPanel
```

But if I try this(showing msg) no output will be shown.
I think i am doing a sth wrong with the order. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Well, your functions _adds_ new controls to the `-AddStatusboxto` target every time you call it, but it never updates or removes any...

Comment: how do it update the elements within it?

Comment: Give the control you want to update a _name_, that way you can identify it later, eg. `$textboxStatusbox.Name = 'UpdatableStatusBox'` - then use `$AddStatusboxto.Controls.Where({$_.Name -eq 'UpdatableStatusBox'})` to locate it again on second invocation

Comment: ```$textboxStatusbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,0)``` - in your ```else``` case, the status box is zero pixels wide / high. (And as an aside, the ```Location``` property expects a ```Point```, not a ```Size```).